# Publishing fails after unpublishing

Tags: webrtc, opentok, tokbox

In my application I do the following steps:

1. Publish audio only
2. Unpublish
3. Publish audio+video
4. Unpublish
5. Publish audio only

At stage 5 it fails with the following error:

> index.js:460 OT.Publisher.onPublishingTimeoutonPublishingTimeout @
>   index.js:460(anonymous function) @ index.js:1472 index.js:332
>   OT.Publisher State Change Failed: 'Failed' cannot transition to
>   'MediaBound'stateChangeFailed @ index.js:332signalChangeFailed @
>   generate_simple_state_machine.js:38handleInvalidStateChanges @
>   generate_simple_state_machine.js:55set @
>   generate_simple_state_machine.js:65onPublishingTimeout @
>   index.js:477(anonymous function) @ index.js:1472 ot_error.js:341
>   OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg:
>   ICEWorkflow_exceptionHandler @
>   ot_error.js:341OTError.handleJsException @
>   ot_error.js:412onPublishingTimeout @ index.js:493(anonymous function)
>   @ index.js:1472 handle.js:1071 1500 "Session.publish :: Could not
>   publish in a reasonable amount of time"

I could reproduce this in all devices that were accessible  to me at that time:

- Chrome on iMac
- Firefox on iMac
- Chrome on Macbook pro
- Chrome on
- Android 4.x

Comment: Ensure each camera has its own USB socket. I had issues with two on a single unpowered hub.

Answer (score 0):

I work at TokBox on the OpenTok JS SDK. I believe this is similar to a known bug we have recently fixed and will be shipped in the next version 2.9.

The known bug did not differentiate between audio/video, it was:

1. Publish audio+video
2. Unpublish
3. Publish audio+video
4. Unpublish
5. Publish audio+video

And then failure.

I believe the fix for this would also apply to your problem (the same underlying problem causes both).

Comment: Thanks Michael! Can I try OpenTok.js beta version?

Comment: By the way, this question is a duplicate of https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206550223-Publishing-fails-after-unpublishing I wasn't getting any replies there. I hope that forum is alive :-)

Comment: @HappyCoder you may use https://tbdev.tokbox.com/v2/js/opentok.js to confirm the bug is fixed. Please keep in mind this is a dev build and we cannot guarantee stability of this build, so it's probably best not to use it in any sort of production setting.

Comment: I tried but it says my session token is invalid. I guess I have to write to support and request access to beta API?